# Find if one column of dataframe contains text from column of another dataframe and add a third column where there is a match

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, nlp

I am working in an NLP problem statement in python. I have two dataframes -

DF1 -

| Problem | Region |
| --- | --- |
| I have wrong product | A |
| I have excess payment | A |
| address problem | B |
| I have delayed delivery | C |

DF2 -

| Key | Category |
| --- | --- |
| wrong | Accuracy |
| pay | Pay related |
| delay | Delay related |

I need a final dataframe that checks if 'Problem' contains 'Key'. eg. "pay" exists in "Excess Payment"
If yes then, 'Category' is assigned. So the resultant dataframe will be -

DF3 -

| Problem | Region | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I have wrong product | A | Accuracy |
| I have excess payment | A | Pay related |
| address problem | B |  |
| I have delayed delivery | C | Delay related |

Have found solutions where index needs to match but that is not the case here. Another vague solution is writing multiple str.contains statement but then that is not scalable. Any leads how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a merge on susbtring:

```
import re

# build the regex
# ensure longer strings are used first
# and escape potential special characters
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df2['Key'].sort_values(key=lambda s: s.str.len(), ascending=False)))
# 'wrong|delay|pay'

# perform a left merge
out = df1.merge(df2,
                left_on=df1['Problem'].str.lower()
                           .extract(fr'\b({pattern})',
                                    expand=False),
                right_on='Key', how='left').drop(columns='Key')
```

*NB. here we used a left word boundary (`\b`) to only match the words that **start** with the substring (this way `papaya` wouldn't match `pay`). If this is unwanted and you prefer to match anywhere use `f'({pattern})'` in `extract`.*

Output:

```
                   Problem Region       Category
0     I have wrong product      A       Accuracy
1    I have excess payment      A    Pay related
2          address problem      B            NaN
3  I have delayed delivery      C  Delay related
```

Comment: Was getting an error while using lower() with extract. made a small edit - changed the columns to lower case prior to applying merge and it worked exactly as required. Thank you for the solution!